# How to copy an Oracle 10g server database table into SQL Server 2012 with the help of Web API in C# (no migration)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, oracle10g, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

No migration techniques are allowed as we want to copy the data instead of moving or transferring the data. Data Access: Read Only from Oracle 10g. Visual Studio 2013. SSMS 2012. I tried almost every possible procedure given on the web. This one is SQLBULKCopy.

```
public partial class defaultScribd: System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }

    public void Button1_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string sourcecs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SourceCS"].ConnectionString;
        string destinationCS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DestinationCS"].ConnectionString;

        using(SqlConnection sourcecon = new SqlConnection(sourcecs)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from mfa", sourcecon);
            sourcecon.Open();
            using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                using(SqlConnection destinationcon = new SqlConnection(destinationCS)) {
                    using(SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationcon)) {
                        bc.DestinationTableName = "shub1";
                        destinationcon.Open();
                        bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the errors (if any) being thrown? If there are no errors than what is the issue meaning where does your code not function properly?

Comment: the code needs to be run on visual studio 2013 as we are designing a web Api. There is a logical error in the code as the button is not displayed on the localhost neither any message of error is generated on localpage

Comment: If i understood correctly you have a web page that will have a button to copy data? If so and the button is not showing can you post the front-end code that is supposed to display `Button1`.

Comment: exactly. this is the problem

Comment: there is no button code on aspx / web design side of the page i've hard time in connecting both.

Comment: But why do you have the `Button1_Click` event if there is no button? i am confused here a bit